# Get element id using element class

Tags: javascript, onclick, css-selectors

I'd like to get the id of the pressed element.

I know it's a very common question but I **do not want** a solution in **jquery** (I'm trying to use it as few as possible)
I cannot modify the html, supposing is something like:

```
<p id='123' class='my_class'>x</p>
```

I cannot create something like:

```
<p id='123' class='my_class' onclick='console.log(this.id + " pressed");'>x</p>
```

This is my personal attempt:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_class', this.id, function (id) {
    console.log( id + " pressed!");
});
```

But I keep obtaining this:

```
[object Object] pressed!
```

Comment: what do you mean with "do not want a solution in jQuery"?

Comment: Why this downvote? What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("my_class");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   elems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log(this.id + " pressed");
   });
}
```

Here is solution without jquery.

Comment: This is what i wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost right. Use the below code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.my_class', function () {
  console.log( this.id + " pressed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='123' class='my_class'>x</p>
```

**Explanation**

You should not be sending the third argument with `this` as it is not contextual. The syntax of the `.on` is:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

You can completely ignore the third option and that doesn't matter. Always, inside the function, the `this` will point to the current element, the event is triggered on.

And in your code, you are passing `id` as the parameter to the call back function, which is the `event` (`EventObject`). That's why you got `[Object object]`.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`id` in the arguments points to the `event` object, make it

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_class', this.id, function (id) {
    console.log( id.target.id + " pressed!");
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_class', this.id, function (e) {
    console.log( e.target.id + " pressed!");
});
```